# Layout in html email

Tags: html, css

I've used an html email template and modified it but the email is displaying with a large white margin at the top. How to I reduce this? I'm using android mail client to receive mail and, between the head and top of the page (subject bar), there's too much margin (white space. I'd like to bring the whole thing up to the top of the page

```css
/* ------------------------- 
    ------------
    INLINED WITH 
    htmlemail.io/inline
    ---------------------------- 
    --------- */


/* ------------------------- 
    ------------
    RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE 
    FRIENDLY STYLES
    ---------------------------- 
    --------- */

@media only screen and (max- width: 620px) {
  table[class=body] h1 {
    font-size: 28px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  table[class=body] p,
  table[class=body] ul,
  table[class=body] ol,
  table[class=body] td,
  table[class=body] span,
  table[class=body] a {
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .wrapper,
  table[class=body] .article {
    padding: 10px !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .content {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .container {
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .main {
    border-left-width: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-right-width: 0 !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .btn table {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .btn a {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .img- responsive {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
  }
}


/* ------------------------- 
     ------------
    PRESERVE THESE STYLES IN THE 
    HEAD
    ---------------------------- 
    --------- */

@media all {
  .ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,
  .ExternalClass td,
  .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%;
  }
  .apple-link a {
    color: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }
  #MessageViewBody a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
  }
  .btn-primary table td:hover {
    background-color: #34495e !important;
  }
  .btn-primary a:hover {
    background-color: #34495e !important;
    border-color: #34495e !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="" style="background-color: 
    #f6f6f6; font-family: sans- 
    serif; -webkit-font. 
    smoothing: antialiased; 
    font-size: 14px; line- 
    height: 1.4; margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; -ms-text-size- 
    adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-s 
    size-adjust: 100%;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body" style="border-collapse: 
    separate; mso-table-lspace: 
    0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; 
    width: 100%; background. 
    color: #f6f6f6;">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family: 
    sans-serif; font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td class="container" style="font-family: sans- 
    serif; font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top; 
    display: block; Margin: 0 
    auto; max-width: 580px; 
    padding: 10px; width: 
    580px;">
        <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border. 
    box; display: block; 
    Margin: 0 auto; max-width: 
    580px; padding: 10px;">

          <!-- START CENTERED WHITE 
    CONTAINER -->
          <span class="preheader" style="color: transparent; 
    display: none; height: 0; 
    max-height: 0; max-width: 0; 
    opacity: 0; overflow: 
    hidden; mso-hide: all; 
    visibility: hidden; width: 
    0;">Post an ad today and 
    start selling your unwanted 
    items.</span>
          <table class="main" style="border-collapse: 
    separate; mso-table-lspace: 
    0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; 
    width: 100%; background: 
    #ffffff; border-radius: 
    3px;">

            <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA 
    -->
            <tr>
              <td class="wrapper" style="font-family: sans- 
    serif; font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top; box- 
    sizing: border-box; padding: 
    20px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: 
    separate; mso-table-lspace: 
    0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; 
    width: 100%;">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-family: 
    sans-serif; font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top;">
                      <p style="font-family: sans- 
    serif; font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: normal; margin: 
    0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">.
                      </p>
                      <p style="font-family: sans- 
    serif; font-size: 14px; 
    font- 
    weight: normal; margin: 0; 
    Margin-bottom: 15px;">.
                        <center><img src="http://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
    content/uploads/2019/
    07/Photo_1563667417091.png" alt="Useful alt text" width="300" height="60" border="0" style="border:0; 
    outline:none; text. 
    decoration:none; 
    display:block;"><br><br>.
                        </center>
                        Hey there and welcome to Adsler. Just in case you didn't know, you can also post ads for property, jobs, items wanted or for sale, motors, mobile phones and much more. </p>
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;"><br><br>
                                <center>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #3498db; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;"> <a href="https://adsler.co.uk" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #3498db; border: solid 1px #3498db; border-radius: 5px; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 25px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #3498db;"
                                          rel="https://adsler.co.uk noopener noreferrer">Post Today</a> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </center>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <center>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">Just Click the button</p>
                      </center>
                      <center>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">Happy posting.</p>
                      </center>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
          </table>

          <!-- START FOOTER -->
          <div class="footer" style="clear: both; Margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;">
              <tr>
                <td class="content-block" style="font-family: sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; text-align: center;">
                  <span class="apple-link" style="color: #999999; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">Adsler.co.uk, 49a-49b Friern Barnet Road.</span>
                  <br>
                  <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/contact" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #999999; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;"></a>.
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="content-block powered-by" style="font-family: sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; text-align: center;">
                  <a href="https://adsler.co.uk" style="color: #999999; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;"></a>.
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- END FOOTER -->

          <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Example of changes..

```
<!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
<tr>
<td class="wrapper" style="font- 
family: sans-serif; font-size: 
14px; vertical-align: top; box- 
sizing: border-box; padding: 0 
20px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" style="border. 
collapse: 
separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; 
mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 
100%;">
<tr>
<td style="font-family: sans-serif; 
font-size: 14px; vertical-align: 
top;">
<center><img 
src="http://adsler.co.uk/wp--  
content/uploads/2019/07/Ph
oto_1563667417091.png" alt="Useful 
alt text" width="300" height="60" 
border="0" style="border:0; 
outline:none; text-decoration:none; 
display:block;"><br><br></center>
Hey there and welcome to Adsler. 
Just in case you didn't know, you 
can also post ads for property, 
jobs, items wanted or for sale, 
motors, mobile phones and much 
more.
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" class="btn bt
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple empty `<p>` tags above your header image and the surrounding `<td>` had a 20px padding.

```css
/* ------------------------- 
    ------------
    INLINED WITH 
    htmlemail.io/inline
    ---------------------------- 
    --------- */


/* ------------------------- 
    ------------
    RESPONSIVE AND MOBILE 
    FRIENDLY STYLES
    ---------------------------- 
    --------- */

@media only screen and (max- width: 620px) {
  table[class=body] h1 {
    font-size: 28px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  table[class=body] p,
  table[class=body] ul,
  table[class=body] ol,
  table[class=body] td,
  table[class=body] span,
  table[class=body] a {
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .wrapper,
  table[class=body] .article {
    padding: 10px !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .content {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .container {
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .main {
    border-left-width: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-right-width: 0 !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .btn table {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .btn a {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  table[class=body] .img- responsive {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
  }
}


/* ------------------------- 
     ------------
    PRESERVE THESE STYLES IN THE 
    HEAD
    ---------------------------- 
    --------- */

@media all {
  .ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,
  .ExternalClass td,
  .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%;
  }
  .apple-link a {
    color: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }
  #MessageViewBody a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
  }
  .btn-primary table td:hover {
    background-color: #34495e !important;
  }
  .btn-primary a:hover {
    background-color: #34495e !important;
    border-color: #34495e !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="" style="background-color: 
    #f6f6f6; font-family: sans- 
    serif; -webkit-font. 
    smoothing: antialiased; 
    font-size: 14px; line- 
    height: 1.4; margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; -ms-text-size- 
    adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-s 
    size-adjust: 100%;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body" style="border-collapse: 
    separate; mso-table-lspace: 
    0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; 
    width: 100%; background. 
    color: #f6f6f6;">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family: 
    sans-serif; font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td class="container" style="font-family: sans- 
    serif; font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top; 
    display: block; Margin: 0 
    auto; max-width: 580px; 
    padding: 10px; width: 
    580px;">
        <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border. 
    box; display: block; 
    Margin: 0 auto; max-width: 
    580px; padding: 10px;">

          <!-- START CENTERED WHITE 
    CONTAINER -->
          <span class="preheader" style="color: transparent; 
    display: none; height: 0; 
    max-height: 0; max-width: 0; 
    opacity: 0; overflow: 
    hidden; mso-hide: all; 
    visibility: hidden; width: 
    0;">Post an ad today and 
    start selling your unwanted 
    items.</span>
          <table class="main" style="border-collapse: 
    separate; mso-table-lspace: 
    0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; 
    width: 100%; background: 
    #ffffff; border-radius: 
    3px;">

            <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA 
    -->
            <tr>
              <td class="wrapper" style="font-family: sans- 
    serif; font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top; box- 
    sizing: border-box; padding: 
    0 20px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: 
    separate; mso-table-lspace: 
    0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; 
    width: 100%;">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-family: 
    sans-serif; font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top;">                                           
                        <center><img src="http://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
    content/uploads/2019/
    07/Photo_1563667417091.png" alt="Useful alt text" width="300" height="60" border="0" style="border:0; 
    outline:none; text. 
    decoration:none; 
    display:block;"><br><br>.
                        </center>
<p style="font-family: sans- 
    serif; font-size: 14px; 
    font- 
    weight: normal; margin: 0; 
    Margin-bottom: 15px;">Hey there and welcome to Adsler. Just in case you didn't know, you can also post ads for property, jobs, items wanted or for sale, motors, mobile phones and much more. </p>
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;"><br><br>
                                <center>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #3498db; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;"> <a href="https://adsler.co.uk" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #3498db; border: solid 1px #3498db; border-radius: 5px; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 25px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #3498db;"
                                          rel="https://adsler.co.uk noopener noreferrer">Post Today</a> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </center>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <center>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">Just Click the button</p>
                      </center>
                      <center>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">Happy posting.</p>
                      </center>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
          </table>

          <!-- START FOOTER -->
          <div class="footer" style="clear: both; Margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;">
              <tr>
                <td class="content-block" style="font-family: sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; text-align: center;">
                  <span class="apple-link" style="color: #999999; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">Adsler.co.uk, 49a-49b Friern Barnet Road.</span>
                  <br>
                  <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/contact" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #999999; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;"></a>.
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="content-block powered-by" style="font-family: sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 12px; color: #999999; text-align: center;">
                  <a href="https://adsler.co.uk" style="color: #999999; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;"></a>.
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!-- END FOOTER -->

          <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Changed to `padding: 0 20px;">`? Where are the p tags? Thanks.

Comment: They were immediately before the header image. I've already removed them in my snippet.

Comment: Please see `example of changes` in edited question for what I've done. Is that what you meant? If so doesn't work...

Comment: @Amg Did you run my code snippet? You can see it working in there. That is, unless you're not accounting for the bad image link. If you just want your text to begin at the top of the window, then get rid of that `<img>` and the `<center>` it's wrapped in. Also, one of the `<p>` tags was wrapping the image as well as the first paragraph, so I moved the opening tag to just before the text. Just replace your `<body>` with my answer and you should be good.

Comment: Cool. If it works, don't forget to come back and hit the check for me.